# puppet 4 Duplicate declaration

Tags: puppet

I am getting a duplicate declaration error when I don't think I should.

I am using the following puppet version

```
puppet --version
4.3.2
```

This is the directory structure

```
./manifests
./manifests/site.pp
./modules
./modules/main
./modules/main/manifests
./modules/main/manifests/init.pp
./modules/main/manifests/sub.pp
```

site.pp

```
node default {
 include main
 include main::sub
}
```

init.pp

```
 class main {
  notice("main")
}
```

sub.pp

```
 class main::sub {
  notice("sub")
}
```

I run this command
`puppet apply --modulepath ./modules manifests/site.pp`

It yields this output:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[Main]): main
Notice: Scope(Class[Main::Sub]): sub
Notice: Compiled catalog for black-pearl.hsd1.il.comcast.net in environment production in 0.82 seconds
Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Main] is already declared; cannot redeclare
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, perhaps puppet has a `main` already.  When I substituted `ryan` in for `main` all was well.

```
$ find .
.
./manifests
./manifests/site.pp
./modules
./modules/ryan
./modules/ryan/manifests
./modules/ryan/manifests/init.pp
./modules/ryan/manifests/sub.pp
```

site.pp

```
node default {
  include ryan
  include ryan::sub
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puppet 4 is a lot stricter about names, and there are a number of reserved names, including `main`:

```
Reserved Class Names
The following are built-in namespaces used by Puppet and so must not be used as class names:

main — Puppet automatically creates a main class, which contains any resources not contained by any other class.
```

See https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_reserved.html
for more